# Change table structure from mysql to sqllite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

i want to change database of my simple application from mysql to sqlite, this is my sql command :

```
CREATE TABLE `Todo` (
  `Id`          int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title`       varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category`    varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `State`       varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

im try to create sqllite but return me this error : `Error: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error` how i can fix it ?

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited for https://google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using primary key separately, please mention it with your AUTO INCREMENT key

```
CREATE TABLE `Todo` (
  `Id`          integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,
  `Title`       varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Category`    varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `State`       varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
)
```